# Copy one Feature from one Annotation to another

Tags: uima, ruta

I've got following scenario:

I've created annotations based off from previously executed modules in a pipeline:

```
NormalizedNamedEntity{REGEXP(NormalizedNamedEntity.concept.identifier,"[A-Z0-9]{7}@XXX") -> CREATE(GLATC, "key" = NormalizedNamedEntity.concept.identifier)};
```

Which work perfectly fine.

> Medication:GLATC xmi:id="35535" sofa="16776" begin="1684" end="1693"
>   key="N06AA05@XXX"

I continue to produce annotations.

> Medication:MMedikation xmi:id="40516" sofa="16776" begin="1684"
>   end="1693" MNAME="35339"

Now I want to get the Feature "key" from the GLATC Annotation to be the Feature "ATC" in the MMedikation Annotation.
This is what I tried so far:

```
MMedikation{CONTAINS(GLATC)} -> {MMedikation{ -> SETFEATURE("ATC", temp)} <- {GLATC{ -> GETFEATURE("key", temp)};};};
MMedikation{PARTOF(GLATC)} -> {MMedikation{ -> SETFEATURE("ATC", temp)} <- {GLATC{ -> GETFEATURE("key", temp)};};};
```

To no avail.
Ruta doesn't have any trouble 'understanding' both rules. 
I've tried to see, if the first part is working:

```
MMedikation{CONTAINS(GLATC) -> MARK(MNAME)};
```

correctly marks MNAME Annotations whenever MMedikation contains GLATC.
I've seen that this rule only works when there are no brackets before the first '->', but applying this to the longer rule above:

```
MMedikation{CONTAINS(GLATC) -> MMedikation{-> SETFEATURE("ATC", temp)} <- {GLATC{ -> GETFEATURE("key", temp)};};
```

or

```
MMedikation{CONTAINS(GLATC) -> MMedikation{-> SETFEATURE("ATC", temp)} <- {GLATC{ -> GETFEATURE("key", temp)};};};
```

just yields this Error:

> Error in Ruta3878238602695220973, line 192, "{": expected RCURLY, but
>   found LCURLY

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
K

Comment: Your last two rules are not syntactically correct. There is a implicit action followed by a condition action part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An addition to the correct answer.

The rule

```
MMedikation{CONTAINS(GLATC) -> SETFEATURE("ATC", temp)} <- {GLATC{ -> GETFEATURE("key", temp)};};
```

can be written as

```
m:MMedikation{-> m.ATC = g.key} <- {g:GLATC;};
```

Answer (score 1):

Aparently, I had an error in my train of thought.

I build up the rule from the working bit

```
MMedikation{CONTAINS(GLATC) -> SETFEATURE("ATC", temp)}
```

and added rules up to this rule:

```
MMedikation{CONTAINS(GLATC) -> SETFEATURE("ATC", temp)} <- {GLATC{ -> GETFEATURE("key", temp)};};
```

Which now works.
Yay.

Comment: And I know. Posting a question and answering it within hours yourself... but I got to the point of really gnawing on my keyboard and finally chose to post the question here. And then I thought: Why not go and try rebuilding the rule and not just adding or deleting stuff from the big one?